# Reputation Negative Change Log

Tags: support, reputation, negative-rep

Till yesterday, I had 56 reputation, and right now, I have 46 (This is for StackOverflow). 
It's a change of -10.

Now, 
1. When I logged in, the reputation change log showed "-8" in blue on my profile.
2. When I checked the log, it showed no Negative Reputation anywhere (as you might see in my log).

What exactly happened, and where I lost reputation?

I tried to lookup other similar questions, but couldn't find an answer to this type of scenario. If there's a duplicate, do let me know. :)

Thanks

**EDIT:**

From another Community Wiki Answer:

> **Why would an event disappear from my reputation history?**
>
> This should only occur for upvotes, downvotes, and accepts. Whenever
>   one of these actions gets reversed during the same day, the event is
>   just completely removed from your history rather than creating a
>   separate unupvote, undownvote, or unaccept event in the list. This was
>   done to prevent users clicking a vote on/off repeatedly to fill up a
>   user's history with useless events.

I got my answer. Someone who had upvoted, again downvoted to make no net change in my reputation.
Now I have another question: So, now, how do I know which post was affected, so that I could update my answer if there was something wrong?

Comment: Select the option **Show Removed Posts** at the bottom of the rep page and then see.

Comment: @AsheeshR, nope that still doesn't help.

Comment: There is a 97.3% chance that someone retracted their upvote on one of your answers. That would cause you to lose 10 points, but wouldn't show up as losing reputation.

Comment: Yes, that's the thing that I believe to have happened, so I have another question as updated in my question above.

So, @CodyGray, how did you come to the inference of precisely 97.3 per cent probability? :P

Comment: Nope @CodyGray there is a 97.3445% chance.

Comment: I would show you a picture, but it is NSFW.

Comment: Yeah, that's fine, I am not at work right now ;)
Also, if there's any answer to another question I put, do let me know. :)

Comment: There is no way to know which upvote was retracted unless you saw it being cast (vote count / rep). Basically, a retracted upvote never happened as far as the system is concerned.

Comment: Okay, so now at least I know I can't know that! :P
Thanks @AsheeshR

Comment: @AsheeshR Hang on; is this a recent change?  I see e.g. "-10  01:57  unupvote" on my reputation history; is this only visible to moderators?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard IIRC, when the vote is reversed within the 5 minute grace period, then no record is stored. If it stays for more than 5 minutes, then a record is created. If the post is edited after the vote gets registered (allowing the votes to be retracted), then the rep correction is registered on the profile in the case of a retraction.